# Disabling flow-runtime for all node_modules

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I have a react native project with flow-runtime. When I run it I get:

```
node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Button.js: Decorators are not enabled.
```

I don't want flow-runtime to perform any type validations against node_modules. How do I disable it to not check them?

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/ignore/) says:

> The `[ignore]` section in a `.flowconfig` file tells Flow to ignore files matching the specified regular expressions when type checking your code. By default, nothing is ignored.

This should ignore all `node_modules` at the top-level of your project:

```
[ignore]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/.*
```

It's not recommended though, as you may lose some valid typings too. In this case, consider ignoring a single dependency (like `node_modules/react-native`) or even a single file.

Comment: This is why my question is how to disable flow-runtime for node_modules not flow.

Comment: OK, my bad - it will disable both. According to the newest sources ([1](https://github.com/codemix/flow-runtime/blob/4f1702b179ad3adc2a2f188c1666444979fdb5de/packages/babel-plugin-flow-runtime/src/createConversionContext.js#L18-L56), [2](https://github.com/codemix/flow-runtime/blob/4f1702b179ad3adc2a2f188c1666444979fdb5de/packages/babel-plugin-flow-runtime/src/collectProgramOptions.js#L17-L40)) it's not possible.